# Yocto Image build fails because "nothing RPROVIDES libavresample"

Tags: yocto, imx6

I am trying to build a custom Yocto image based on fsl-image-gui for my iMX6 based board SECO A62J. I use Hob to do this.

After having selected my machine, my layers and my image, I custom my packages list by adding chromium. This automatically selects libexif and libav which are Chromium dependencies. The build of the packages is successful

The last step is the build of the image itself, and this is where my problem appears. I select the packages I want to include in my image, including Chromium, libexif and libav (and its dependencies).

And I got those errors :

> Nothing RPROVIDES 'libavresample' (but
>   /home/adrien/fsl-release-bsp/build_anna/recipes/images/fsl-image-gui-edited-20170131-144607.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)

and

> Required build target 'fsl-image-gui-edited-20170131-144607' has no
>   buildable providers. Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was:
>   ['fsl-image-gui-edited-20170131-144607', 'libavresample']

However, the library libavresample.so is built successfully and can be found  under my build directory in sysroots/"machine_name"/usr/lib/

Why Yocto can't find and include this library in my image, What am I missing here?

Comment: No recipe in your yocto build produces a package called "libavresample". Are you sure you need it? Chromium probably uses its own copy anyway.

Comment: At building packages step, libav is automatically selected as Chromium dependency. That's why I thought I needed it, i'll give it a try without including it in my image.
I thought libavresample was built with libav, if not I have no idea where the libavresample.so in my build directory come from. At building image step, when I select libav, its dependencies are also automatically selected like libavresample, libavcodec etc

Comment: It's complicated: Depending on yocto version libavresample _could_ come from libav or ffmpeg (but is not built by default AFAIR), but it may also be contained in e.g. chromium. When you say you "select libav" what exactly do you mean? None of the libav recipes I've seen even build avresample by default, let alone runtime depend on it... Linking to the recipes might help.

Comment: The reason I'm asking about how you select libav is that you say you get libavresample selected automatically but according to the log your image directly RDEPENDS on libavresample -- there does not seem to be any dependencies in between.

Comment: "select libav" means I use Hob so I have a list of built packages I can include into my image by clicking on them, and their dependencies are automatically selected. With libav, it selects other libraries automatically like libavresample
You're right it makes my image depending on libavresample, I don't actually want this. I'll check if Chromium has its own copy. Maybe I won't need to include libav explicitly.
What leaded me to this is that when I selected Chromium to be built, libav was automatically selected and built too. That's why I thought I needed to include libav  explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

In your local.conf :

```
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST += " commercial"
```

Comment: Variable LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST has been renamed to LICENSE_FLAGS_ACCEPTED